# Is it possible to change behaviour on new tab event in any browser?

Tags: browser, plugins

When you click on the "new tab" button in a browser, let's say Chrome, new tab appears in the end of the existing tab chain.
I wonder if it is any chance to make a broswer put the tab in the head of the chain?
Maybe plugin? Have to dive in firefox codebase?
Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Pretty sure this is up to the browser, but if tabs are stored in an array style format, you may be able to pop one in at the start, but afaik you can't. (Don't take my word for it)

Comment: OK, ignore my comment from before. With chrome you can just use Chrome.tabs.create and set the index to 0, which would put it at the start. I'm not sure how hard it would be to manipulate the actual default action though. But you may be able to do this with a plugin. Not sure if you can do this with firefox, but considering they're moving over to the chrome style of extensions, it should work the same.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with Chrome Extention
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabtohead/iipdefkdfmbhnelbhlbdamplokbnpkhe